# How to add multiple elements in a list together by index?

Tags: python, list, element

How do you add the elements of a list together by index (simple math)?

For example:

```
a = 123456789

b = a[0] + a[2] + a[6] #does not work

print (b)
```

However, I want this sort of outcome:

```
b == 11
```

Comment: by your notation a is not a list its a huge number. u want to add all the numbers of a large number ?If a is a list it looks like `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and all u need is `sum(a)`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, if I've answered your question, if you accept it, you'll get plus two to your reputation. You get an upvote from me for the diversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn Python's types. First, you want to treat your numbers as a string, so make it a string literal:

```
a = '123456789'
```

Now you need to coerce each part of the string that's selected to an integer, with `int`:

```
b = int(a[0]) + int(a[2]) + int(a[6]) #Works!
```

You can also store the string as a list, so you don't have to coerce to ints for each one:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

or

```
a = range(1,10) # in python 2
a = list(range(1,10)) # in python 3
```

then

```
b = a[0] + a[2] + a[6]

print(b)
```

prints `11`

and now this should return `True`

```
b == 11
```

Comment: Careful - they think they're making a list, not a string. Though this answer is completely viable, I think `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` would be more appropriate in this context

Comment: Given that the asker doesn't know how to use a string, I think the meaning is rather generalized, but I'll add that.

Comment: Truth. I suppose I'm assuming they know how to differentiate a list from a string - not necessarily true if they can't differentiate a list/string from an int :P

Comment: And if one really wanted to: `sum(map(int, itemgetter(0, 2, 6)(str(a))))` (removing the conversion if needed)

Comment: @JonClements but that's going a bit too far, don't you think? :D

Comment: @AaronHall in this case, definitely. But if you wanted the 3rd, 12th, 15th, 19th, 21st, 35th, 91st, 101st, 123rd digits (which may be programmatically generated) etc... etc... - it becomes a quite nice generic method

Comment: Not the best of examples, but it is 3am :): `r = range(100); sum(itemgetter(*random.sample(r, 6))(r))`